# How do you use the URL site column in a display template?

Tags: 2013, display-template

I've added a URL site column to my custom list. However URL isn't accessible in my display template.

I want to do something like:

```
var url = ctx.CurrentItem.URL;
```

Here's my current display template:

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
<head>
<title>My Item</title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Displays the default result item template.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">&#39;Title&#39;:&#39;Title&#39;,&#39;Path&#39;:&#39;Path&#39;,&#39;Description&#39;:&#39;Description&#39;,&#39;EditorOWSUSER&#39;:&#39;EditorOWSUSER&#39;,&#39;LastModifiedTime&#39;:&#39;LastModifiedTime&#39;,&#39;CollapsingStatus&#39;:&#39;CollapsingStatus&#39;,&#39;DocId&#39;:&#39;DocId&#39;,&#39;HitHighlightedSummary&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedSummary&#39;,&#39;HitHighlightedProperties&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedProperties&#39;,&#39;FileExtension&#39;:&#39;FileExtension&#39;,&#39;ViewsLifeTime&#39;:&#39;ViewsLifeTime&#39;,&#39;ParentLink&#39;:&#39;ParentLink&#39;,&#39;FileType&#39;:&#39;FileType&#39;,&#39;IsContainer&#39;:&#39;IsContainer&#39;,&#39;SecondaryFileExtension&#39;:&#39;SecondaryFileExtension&#39;,&#39;DisplayAuthor&#39;:&#39;DisplayAuthor&#39;,&#39;URL&#39;:&#39;URL&#39;</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">http://van-devmoss1/sites/ppisolutions/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_MyItem.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Item_MyItem">
<!--#_ 
        if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){ 
            console.log(ctx.CurrentItem);
            console.log(ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
            console.log(ctx.CurrentItem.Path);
            console.log(ctx.CurrentItem.URL);
            var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
            var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
            var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
            var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default_HoverPanel.js";
            $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
            if(ctx.CurrentItem.IsContainer){
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getFolderIconUrl();
            }
            ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
            ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
_#-->
            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" name="Item" data-displaytemplate="DefaultItem" class="ms-srch-item">
                _#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#_  
            </div>
<!--#_ 
        } 
_#-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try `ctx.CurrentItem.Path`

Comment: That gives me the path to the item (something.DispForm.aspx?ID=3). But it doesn't give me the value I've entered in the URL site column.

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Comment: Please see updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Managed Properties` of `URL` from

Site Settings -> Search Schema -> Search using `Managed property`

Once you find the property name you need to update it in `ManagedPropertyMapping` tag and then access it using

```
ctx.CurrentItem.ManagedPropertyNameOfURL
```

Comment: The problem is if I search through the schema for URL I get 25 results, but none stand out as what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can use build query and try combinations till you figure out the actual property name

Comment: Using "Build your Query" I can filter using a property called URLOWSURLH. But if I add that to my ManagedPropertMapping tag it comes out as undefined.

Comment: I can also filter my query using OWS_URL, but again if I add this to ManagedPropertMapping tag I get undefined.

Comment: @matt it seems you are using crawled property instead of managed property.

Comment: But it's in my sub-sites's list of Managed Properties? I'm confused.

Comment: I also have the same problem - the property URLOWSURLH is a mapped property and if I choose an OOTB display template like 2 Lines and set the managed property in the web part to be URLOWSURLH it shows up. However, if I create my own display template based on 2 Lines and set one of those managed properties to use URLOWSURLH I get nothing and it shows as Undefined in the debugger. What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try: ctx.CurrentItem["URL.desc"]

Answer (score 1):

Steps Use URL Site Column in Display Template

1. Create Source List
2. Add URL Column
3. Add Sample Content to List
4. Run Search Crawl (Incremental)
5. In Central Admin > Search Administration > Search Schema
6. Create New Managed Property
7. Properties (Text, Query, Search, Retrieve, and Safe)
8. Mappings to Crawled Properties (ows_URL)
9. Run Search Crawl (FULL)
10. Add Content Search WP to your page and Set "Your New Managed Property Name" to the Link URL under Property Mappings Field

Source(s): This blog helped me a bit http://www.kbasrai.com/b/2014/08/25/find-items-where-url-field-contains-the-site-url

Good Luck
-Schuess